# Is there some $Ext$ group that classifies extensions in the **Derived Category**?

Tags: abelian-categories, higher-category-theory, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category, we have $D(\mathcal{A})$

For $A,C \in \mathcal{A}$, we know that $Ext^1(A,C)$ classifies extensions $0 \to C \to B \to A \to 0$

I want an analog for $Der(\mathcal{A})$.

Exact sequences should be replaced with distinguished triangles. A splitting condition is precisely that the natural element in $(A,C[1])$ vanishes. But $Hom(A,C[1])$ doesn't classify distinguished triangles, indeed if $\mathcal{A} = Vect$ then all distinguished triangles split, but $Hom(A,C[1])$ can be nonzero.

In other words there is a map $A \to C[1]$ that can't be raised to a distinguished triangle I guess?

Thus my question is, is there a way to compute the class of distinguished triangles $C \to B \to A$?

Comment: To answer your first question, it is an axiom of triangulate categories that every morphism $A \to B$ can be extended to a distinguished triangle, and the cone of this morphism is unique up to (non-unique) isomorphism.

Comment: @DKS You can take the fiber $B$ of $A \to C[1]$ but no one promises you that there is a map $C  \to B$ completing it to a triangle

Comment: If your definition of a distinguished triangle being split is that the natural element of $\operatorname{Hom}(A,C[1])$ vanishes, then it is not true that all distinguished triangles in the derived category of $\mathsf{Vect}$ split.